# Where in the database can I get the country name that matches addr_countrycode

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2011, sage-crm

I am using Sage CRM and creating reports in Crystal Reports 2011

I would like to display the country name that is in Addr table but it only has a code IE for Ireland.

So my question is, where do I get the value Ireland (instead of IE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go here:

[http://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/ctycodes.htm#.Ud6_XW39w24][1]

and get all the country codes.  You will have to write some kind of implementation that maps the codes to the names.  Now this will work assuming your database uses standard country codes.

Another thing to look at is how did the country codes get in your database in the first place?  Obviously there is some function that maps country names to codes.  Simply write the inverse of that function.

See having an understanding of math does help one in life.

Comment: Hi the problem is that an external company CRM have made the database and populate it so I was wondering if anyone creating reports from Sage CRM through crystal has come accross this problem

Answer (score 3):

The Country field in CRM is a Selection List based on the translation from the custom_captions table. If you run a query such as:

```
Select addr_address1,
(select capt_uk from custom_captions where capt_code = addr_country and capt_family = 'addr_country') as addr_country
From address
```

This will return the value shown on screen rather than the code in the database.